# ¿Por qué "rata" es una "persona tacaña"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, modismos

**[Rata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VDVMHBM)** es, según el DRAE:

> 7. m. y f. coloq. Persona tacaña.

¿Cómo adquirió ese significado?

Answer (score 2):

Sin duda ha de tener que ver con su naturaleza roedora... las ratas se meten en las despensas y roban toda la comida que pueden, roen y rompen cosas. Además la rata ha sido considerada un animal perjudicial, transmisor de enfermedades y demás. (Me parece un juicio injusto contra un animal que solamente intenta sobrevivir, como cualquier otro.)

En muchos sitios no sólo es sinónimo de tacaño, sino en general de todo tipo de persona despreciable.

Comment: Efectivamente, la acepción 3 de la palabra **rata**  en el Diccionario de la Real Academia, cuyo enlace aparece en texto de la pregunta, es precisamente ***Persona despreciable***.

Comment: @Jdamian nótese que hoy en día la palabra "rata" como persona despreciable viene de "ratero", y "ratero" según Covarrubias en su diccionario de 1611, significa "el hõbre de baxos pensamientos, tomada la metafora de ciertas aves de rapiña, que caçan ratones". Por tanto, esa acepción viene del ratón como presa, y no como animal malo o perjudicial.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que este es uno de esos casos en los que la expresión no tiene nada que ver con el animal. Hay varios caminos posibles por los que se pueda haber llegado a esa acepción, vamos a analizarlas:

### Rata como "bolsillo"

En la definición actual de "rata" se puede ver que significa "bolsillo del vestido". Esta es una acepción antigua, ya existente desde el primer diccionario de la RAE de 1737 (tomo O-R), y usada únicamente en la zona de la germanía (aunque algunos autores del siglo XVIII dicen que también se usaba en la jerga gitana). En el diccionario de 1780 se define "rata" como "faltriquera". Y "ratero" de la siguiente forma:

> RATERO. El ladrón que hurta cosas de poco valor, ó de las faltriqueras.

Posteriormente, en 1899 se incorporó a "rata" la acepción de lo mismo que "ratero". Teniendo en cuenta que un "rata" es aquel que prefiere que el dinero esté en su propio bolsillo ("rata") antes que en bolsillo ajeno, tampoco es descabellado que se le haya dado ese nombre a los avaros y tacaños.

### Rata como "parte proporcional"

Ya en 1611, Covarrubias definía "rata" como

> [...] lo que a cada uno le pueda caber de la cota principal repartida entre muchos [...]

y hoy en día se define como "parte proporcional". Esta acepción proviene directamente del latín, al contrario que la del animal, que es de origen incierto (algunos dicen que viene del germánico o del alto alemán). Luego tenemos la definición de "ratear" de 1737:

> Disminuir ò rebaxar à proporción y prorata.

que es exactamente igual a la de hoy en día. Y añade el siguiente ejemplo:

> Si por algun accidente iba tarde à trabajar, lo *rateaba* de su jornál, aunque no fuesse mas de media hora, y se le volvia a su dueño.

Este ejemplo es totalmente lo que hoy se consideraría a un "rata": a alguien que ratea, que te escatima con el dinero.

Personalmente apuesto más por esta segunda versión, aunque el hecho de que "rata" se usara como "ratero" posiblemente también haya ayudado.